# How do i give numbers to permutation of n elements?

Tags: java, permutation

```java
public static void permute(String str, int l, int r) {
        
    if (l == r) {
        System.out.println(""+str+"");
    }
    else {
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        
            str = swap(str,l,i);
            permute(str, l+1, r);
            str = swap(str,l,i);
        
        }
    }
}
```

suppose the given String permuted is "abc". the output i get is:

```
        abc
        acb
        bac
        bca
        cba
        cab
```

I need the output something like this:

```
        [123] abc
        [132] acb
        [213] bac
        [231] bca
        [321] cba
        [312] cab
```

*I get the permutation as output but I'm not able to understand where and what to print the corresponding numbers of permutation. a number is assigned to each letter, 1 to a, 2 to b, 3 to c.*

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep most of your code so you may understand it easily.
I create a String named `indices` which contains indices values from `start` to `end` aggregated with empty String `""`.
Then I swap the provided String and my indices using your method.

```java
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        permute("abc");
    }

    public static void permute(String str) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = str.length() -1;
        String indices = IntStream.range(start, end+1).mapToObj(i -> Integer.toString(i+1)).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
        permute(str, indices, start, end);
    }

    public static void permute(String str, String indices, int l, int r) {
        if (l == r) {
            System.out.println("[" + indices + "] " +str);
        } else {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {

                String permuted = swap(str,l,i);
                String indicesPermuted = swap(indices,l,i);
                permute(permuted, indicesPermuted, l+1, r);

            }
        }
    }

    public static String swap(String str, int source, int dest) {
        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
        charArray[source] = str.charAt(dest);
        charArray[dest] = str.charAt(source);
        return String.valueOf(charArray);
    }
}
```

Please note that this code works because 1 letter corresponds to 1 number (index).
When your string is longer than 10 chars indices won't be correct.
Please consider use `List` and swap List items over String like this

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        permute("abc");
    }

    public static void permute(String str) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = str.length() -1;
        List<Integer> indices = IntStream.range(start, end+1).mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(i+1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        permute(str, indices, start, end);
    }

    public static void permute(String str, List<Integer> indices, int l, int r) {
        if (l == r) {
            System.out.println(indices + " " + str);
        } else {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {

                String permuted = swap(str,l,i);
                swap(indices,l,i);
                permute(permuted, indices, l+1, r);

            }
        }
    }

    public static String swap(String str, int source, int dest) {
        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
        charArray[source] = str.charAt(dest);
        charArray[dest] = str.charAt(source);
        return String.valueOf(charArray);
    }

    public static void swap(List<Integer> list, int source, int dest) {
        Integer tmp = list.get(source);
        list.set(source, list.get(dest));
        list.set(dest, tmp);
    }
}
```

A more complex solution is to convert your `String str` to another `List` and use a generic `swap` with diamond operator.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        permute("abc");
    }

    public static void permute(String str) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = str.length() -1;
        List<Integer> indices = IntStream.range(start, end+1).mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(i+1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Character> chars = str.chars().mapToObj(e -> (char) e).collect(Collectors.toList());
        permute(chars, indices, start, end);
    }

    public static void permute(List<Character> str, List<Integer> indices, int l, int r) {
        if (l == r) {
            System.out.println(indices + " " + str);
        } else {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {

                swap(str,l,i);
                swap(indices,l,i);
                permute(str, indices, l+1, r);

            }
        }
    }

    public static <T> void swap(List<T> list, int source, int dest) {
        T tmp = list.get(source);
        list.set(source, list.get(dest));
        list.set(dest, tmp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a little function like this:

```
public String convertToNumbers (String str) {

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("[");

  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    sb.append(str.codePointAt(i) - "a".codePointAt(0) + 1) ;
  }

  sb.append("] " + str);
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Replace the

```
System.out.println(""+str+"");
```

with

```
System.out.println(convertToNumbers(str));
```